# Flashing-background CSS animation works in JSFiddle but not on WordPress (Elementor) page

Tags: wordpress, css-animations, elementor, flashing

(MacOS / Chrome)
I have the following code:

```css
.flash {
    animation: pulse 1s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes pulse {
    0%   { background: transparent; }
    100% { background: green; }
}
```

```html
<span class=flash>Foo</span>
```

It correctly pulses the background colour between green and transparent at 2Hz.

(Note: It also runs correctly renders correctly in Chrome if I create an HTML file).

Now in my WordPress page, I edit with Elementor, I create a fresh text block, I give it class `flash`, but now it is pulsing the FOREGROUND colour between the original colour (blue) and transparent.

As a further test, I create a raw HTML block: `<span class=flash>bar</span>` and observe this behaves exactly the same way.

Now it gets stranger: if I replace my CSS with:

```
.flash {
    animation: pulse 10s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}
```

... it still behaves exactly the same. (I changed the period to 10 seconds to make sure there is not some cache error with Chrome). It's still animates -- even though I have flushed my cache and removed the animation definition block.

This is a test case.  The original code failed to animate the HTML element in my plug-in at all!  However I suspect if I am able to resolve this behaviour, it will shake the original problem loose.

How to proceed further with the investigation?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I was experiencing a double name-collision: WordPress has `.css` files defining both `flash` and `pulse`.

If I rename both of these tokens to `pi-flash` and `pi-pulse`, the problem is resolved.